# Python3: Shared Array with strings between processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I want to share a list with strings between processes, but unfortunately I receive the error message "ValueError: character U+169ea10 is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]".

Here is the Python 3 code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Array, Lock
from ctypes import c_wchar_p
import time

def run_child(a):
    time.sleep(2)
    print(a[0]) # print foo
    print(a[1]) # print bar
    print(a[2]) # print baz
    print("SET foofoo barbar bazbaz")
    a[0] = "foofoo"
    a[1] = "barbar"
    a[2] = "bazbaz"

lock = Lock()
a = Array(c_wchar_p, range(3), lock=lock)
p = Process(target=run_child, args=(a,))
p.start()

print("SET foo bar baz")
a[0] = "foo"
a[1] = "bar"
a[2] = "baz"

time.sleep(4)

print(a[0]) # print foofoo
print(a[1]) # print barbar
print(a[2]) # print bazbaz
```

Does someone knows what I am doing wrong?

Regards
Jonny

Comment: You mast use bytes instead of strings if you are dealing with ctypes.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ctype` doesn't match the content of your `Array`.  Your initializing data should be a list of strings to match the `ctype` you're specifying.  You're initializing it with `range(3)`, which evaluates to integers, not strings.

Should be more like

```
a = Array(c_wchar_p, ('', '', ''), lock=lock)
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_wchar_p)

> c_wchar_p
>
> Represents the C wchar_t * datatype, which must be a pointer to a zero-terminated wide character string.   The constructor accepts an integer address, or a string.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint!