# How to share string between processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I have the hardest time to share a string between processes. I looked at the following [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484764/multiprocessing-value-clear-syntax/16485061#16485061), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290960/how-to-share-a-string-amongst-multiple-processes-using-managers-in-python), [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35234634/python3-shared-array-with-strings-between-processes) but still fail in an actual example. If I understood the docs correctly, looking should be done automatically therefore there should be no race condition with setting/reading. Here's what I've got:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing
import ctypes
import time

SLEEP = 0.1
CYCLES = 20

def child_process_fun(share):
    for i in range(CYCLES):
        time.sleep(SLEEP)
        share.value = str(time.time())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    share = multiprocessing.Value(ctypes.c_wchar_p, '')
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=child_process_fun, args=(share,))
    process.start()

    for i in range(CYCLES):
        time.sleep(SLEEP)
        print(share.value)
```

which produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "test2.py", line 23, in <module>
       print(share.value)
    File "<string>", line 5, in getvalue
ValueError: character U+e479b7b0 is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]
```

**Edit**: ´id(share.value)´ is different for each process. However if I try a double as shared variable instead they are the same and it works like a charm. Could this be a python bug?

Comment: Did you take a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)?

Comment: @pstatix I did, but I was under the impression that having shared memory does not require going over pipes or similar in order to share a state. And that multiprocessing.Value (https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing%20value#multiprocessing.Value) should do this job.

Comment: Your processes are separate, how do you expect them to know the address of a process specific variable within the other?

Comment: If you want to stick with `Value` look [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/04/shared-counter-with-pythons-multiprocessing)

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to share items between processes in my opinion is a Pipe (this article is a great resource for that: https://superfastpython.com/multiprocessing-pipe-in-python/).

Basically the Pipe sends strings back and forth between two,and only two, processes (you can work around this by piping everything to a "switchboard" process that relays messages based on tags).

Here is a quick overview of the API

```
# Create Pipe
from multiprocessing import Pipe
frontend_pipe, backend_pipe = Pipe()

# Send string
frontend_pipe.send("Example: instructions can also be parsed using str.split(': ')")

# Recieve string
string = backend_pipe.recv()

# Two-way communication
backend_pipe.send("Finished")
```

The pipe.recv() method will block the event loop until it receives a string.

Why it is my preferred method is any object that can be pickled can also be shared between objects using a Pipe using pipe.send_bytes() and pipe.recv_bytes().